# setting java 18 on my iMac as default version from java 8

Tags: java, settings, default, osx-elcapitan

so, I got a new external monitor for my iMac, and was downloading the latest Java -- java18 -- from java 8.  I hadn't used the machine for years, but since getting my new monitor a couple weeks ago, I'm happy to know that I can still use it.  I had written it off after the backlight went out, but lo and behold, the machine stills works fine.

Anyway, I downloaded Java 18 from the oracle website, installed it with no problem, but when I go the terminal app and enter
java -version it still says java 1.8 (java 8).  I looked in the java folder in the library directory, and sure enough the java 18 folder is there, but for some reason it won't or doesn't 'see' it as the current/default java version.

Anyone out there have any help to give?  I'm not sure what terminal commands to use to make this the default version.  maybe because it's so far from the version that was on there.   Can anyone help me out?   The machine is a 2010 iMac 11,6 running El Capitan, and I want to use it while it lasts, as I gradually switch over to Linux.

The machine still works great, and the latest version that was on it before this download was java 8.   I'm not at the machine right now, so i'll have to look at this over the next few days.

Comment: Try `/usr/libexec/java_home -V` to see what's installed; look for profile that sets `JAVA_HOME` to the earlier version.

Comment: okay -- i entered the command, and it shows only the versions up to java 8, but when I open the finder window, it shows the folder for Java 18 here.   So what do I do?

Comment: I'd start over; an Oracle [.dmg](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#jdk18-mac) should know how to install itself in the right place.

Comment: I did that, but the result is the same.  Can you think of any other suggestions?  I've always downloaded/installed java like this.  Any idea where I'd look to see the JAVA_HOME variable? My apologies if I'm being redundant

Comment: trash god -- I also tried updating to 18.2, from your link, but the result is the same.  It's in the Java Virtual Machines folder, (the name of the directory is JDK 18.2) but it's not the default -- ever after I temporarily put all the other versions in the trash as a test, when java -version is entered it doesn't find any JVM.

Comment: Oh, and by the way /usr/libexec/java_home -V returns "no such file or directory.  Can you tell me the difference between java_home and JAVA_HOME?  I'm confused.  It's been a while as well since I've been in the terminal

Comment: Try `xcode-select -v`, `which java` and `echo $JAVA_HOME`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add in `~/.profile` file (create it, if doesn't exist), the setting of `JAVA_HOME` environment variable, pointing to your Java18 installation directory:

```
JAVA_HOME=/Path/to/Java18
export JAVA_HOME;
```

source: http://www.sajeconsultants.com/how-to-set-java_home-on-mac-os-x/

In case of failure, try to do the same but in the files:
`~/.base_profile`
`~/.zshrc`
source: https://www.developerlibs.com/2022/06/java-environment-path-setup-windows-linux-Mac.html

Comment: Okay, -- I entered your above command for JAVA_HOME, put it in my .profile in my home folder, but still java -version is 1.8.   I don't understand hat's going on.  There is no .base_profile or .zshrc file in my home folder.